# Angular + bootstrap - collapse rows

Tags: angular, grid, bootstrap-4

I'm using `bootstrap` `collapse` functionality to show a details row when I click on a button. It works fine, unless the details row always shows in the same position, that is below the first row. I want it to show below the row where I selected the button. Here's my code:

```
<div *ngIf="pratiche">
  <div class="row" id="list" *ngFor="let p of pratiche">
    <div class="col-1"></div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <div>
        <p>{{ p.id }}<br>
          <span>{{ p.banca }}</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <p>{{ p.statoOperativo }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <p>{{ p.richiedente }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <p>{{ p.dataSopralluogo * 1000 | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <p>{{ p.dataUltimaAzione * 1000 | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1" id="clock">
      <button class="fa fa-clock-o" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#details"></button>
    </div>
    <!-- details row -->
    <div class="row-fluid collapse" id="details">
      <!-- time details header -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class=col-1></div>
        <div class="col"><p>Giorni effettivi</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>1° step</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>2° step</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>3° step</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>4° step</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>Giorni netti</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>SLA 1</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>SLA 2</p></div>
        <div class="col">Giorni consegna</div>
        <div class=col-1></div>
      </div> <!-- end -->
      <!-- time details -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class=col-1></div>
        <div class="col"><p>{{p.giorniEffettivi}}</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>{{p.step1}}</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>{{p.step2}}</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>{{p.step3}}</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>{{p.step4}}</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>{{p.giorniNetti}}</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>{{p.sla1}}</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>{{p.sla2}}</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>{{p.giorniConsegna}}</p></div>
        <div class=col-1></div>
      </div><!-- end -->
    </div> <!-- end details row -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using bootstrap `grid system`. Could anyone give me an hint? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After a long morning spent browsing and trying different approaches, I found a solution. Works like a charm and I didn't have to change my code so much. I ditched the `bootstrap collapse` class though.
To show one detail row at time I had to keep track of the item index in my `ngFor`, and show the details only if the index matches the current row item index.
Hope this helps someone.

**app.component.html**

```
[...some other code...]
<div *ngIf="pratiche">
  <div class="row" id="list" *ngFor="let p of pratiche">
    <div class="col-1"></div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <div>
        <p>{{ p.id }}<br>
          <span>{{ p.banca }}</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <p>{{ p.statoOperativo }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <p>{{ p.richiedente }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <p>{{ p.dataSopralluogo * 1000 | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <p>{{ p.dataUltimaAzione * 1000 | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1" id="clock">
      <button class="fa fa-clock-o" (click)="showSelected(p.id)"></button>
    </div>

    <!-- details row -->
    <div class="row-fluid" id="details" *ngIf="selected && p.id == selectedId">
      <!-- time details header -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class=col-1></div>
        <div class="col"><p>Giorni effettivi</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>1° step</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>2° step</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>3° step</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>4° step</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>Giorni netti</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>SLA 1</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>SLA 2</p></div>
        <div class="col">Giorni consegna</div>
        <div class=col-1></div>
      </div> <!-- end -->
      <!-- time details -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class=col-1></div>
        <div class="col"><p>{{p.giorniEffettivi}}</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>{{p.step1}}</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>{{p.step2}}</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>{{p.step3}}</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>{{p.step4}}</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>{{p.giorniNetti}}</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>{{p.sla1}}</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>{{p.sla2}}</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>{{p.giorniConsegna}}</p></div>
        <div class=col-1></div>
      </div><!-- end -->
    </div> <!-- end details row -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  selected : boolean;
  selectedId: number;

  constructor() {
    this.selected = false;
   }

  ngOnInit() {}

  showSelected(rowId){
        this.selected = !this.selected;
        this.selectedId = rowId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help to expand row(exactly under same row) when clicking on show details and hide it when again click on it.

**Html**

```
      <div class="row" *ngFor="let item of items">
         <div class="col">{{item.name}}</div>
         <div class="col">{{item.address}}</div>
         <div class="col" (click)="showDetails(item)">{{showDetails ? 'Hide Details' : 'Show Details'}}</div>
         <div class="row" *ngIf="showDetails && item.id === selectedItemId">
         <div>details</div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

**code in ts**

```
     selectedItemId;
     showDetails = false;

     showDetails(item) {
     this.selectedItemId = item.id;
     this.showDetails = !this.showDetails;
    }
```